# How to Convert time interval in oracle to number of days in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Goal: My goal is to get the time difference of when status was updated.

Attempted: I attempted the code below and this returns: number of days, hours:min:ss

```
SELECT RecordID,
lag(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY Billetnum ORDER BY timestamp)
AS PriorStamp
FROM Tracker;
```

Problem: I'm trying to only get the number of days.

Comment: How your end result should look alike? Please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: What you are reporting can't be true. If you are getting a result in number of days, hours:min:ss, then you must be taking a difference in your query, and your query doesn't show that. Anyway: the simplest way to do what you want, assuming "timestamp" is the name of a column of timestamp data type, is to wrap the timestamps within `cast(... as date)`. This will convert the timestamps to dates, and then the differences will be (possibly fractional) number of days, instead of day-to-second intervals as they are when the operands are timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

I created a [db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=249c2cd1ad2a32239c85d2197cfbc2e4) to demonstrate what needs to happen.

Your query needs to take the difference of the current value of `TIMESTAMP` and the previous TIMESTAMP, and then extract the days from the result:

```
SELECT RecordID,
       lag(TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY Billetnum ORDER BY TIMESTAMP)
         AS PriorStamp,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM TIMESTAMP - lag(TIMESTAMP) OVER (PARTITION BY Billetnum ORDER BY TIMESTAMP))
         AS DAYS_DIFF
  FROM Tracker
```